# rails generic fields_for - forcing a child index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model

```
class Person < AR

end
```

Controller

```
def new
  @people = []
  3.times {@people << Person.new)
end
```

View

```
=form_tag :people_form do
 -@people.each_with_index do |person, i|
   =fields_for :person, person do |person_fields|
    =person_fields.text_field :name
```

It is somewhat obvious that this will generate the same html for each person (name = people_form[person][name]).  Is there a way I can get it to insert the index so each for in the person for is unique? (without javacript hack).

For example it would be nice if I could get it to generate something like this:

```
<input name='people_form[0][name]' />
<input name='people_form[1][name]' />
```

Comment: did it work? let us know

Answer (score 0):

simpler than you think

```
=form_tag :people_form do
 -@people.each_with_index do |person, i|
   =fields_for "people_form[#{i}]", person do |person_fields|
    =person_fields.text_field :name
```

Comment: Nope, it's not. This creates input with `people_form[people_form[0]][name]`, not `people_form[people_form][0][name]` .

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 6, you can use the `index` option.

```
fields_for :person, person, index: i do |person_fields|
```